# Waiting until another sound is finished before playing a new one

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, audio

I am developing an iPhone application that plays sounds.  I do not want interrupt or play another sound, if a sound is already playing, regardless of where it was "spawned" from to play.  My code is as follows:

```
if(distance <= 10)
{
   NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"];
   SystemSoundID soundID;
   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
}
```

Simply, I do not want to play a new sound if one is already playing.

I do not want to queue another sound to play if one is already playing.

Is this possible?

Comment: You probably want [AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use the AVAudioPlayer API rather than AudioServicesPlaySystemSound.  It has a delegate which you can use, which defines a method -audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully: which will tell you when your sound finishes playing.  The AVPlayer class also has a -playing method which you can check to see if a sound is currently playing.

So, in other words, do this instead:

```
NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundPath error:&error];
if(!player)
   [self doSomethingWithError:error];
[player setDelegate:self];
[player play];
```