# How to detect which program is using speaker in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion

For example, if Safari starts playing a YouTube video and uses internal or external speaker to playing sound, is there any way to detect this event in Cocoa or something else?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search pointed me to this thread [Waiting until another sound is finished before playing a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697639/waiting-until-another-sound-is-finished-before-playing-a-new-one)

I have not personally tried as yet but will later today and can confirm. I have a project I am working on that includes the same r